# Removing the top 2.5% from my data set in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a dataset with 4 columns in PowerBI.

I would like to use the last column, which has a type of int, and remove all data that is in the top 2.5%.
Each row has an ID, so based on the last column, if it falls under the top 2.5%, then that whole row should be removed from the data set.

How can I do this?

Comment: This may be of some help, using a top N report-level filter https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Display-only-Top-3-percentage-values-in-a-Table-and-remove-the/td-p/404668

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Query Editor by selecting only rows where the count of integers in the column which are greater than the integer in the current row divided by the total count of all rows is greater than 2.5%. (If fewer than 2.5% of all values are less than the integer in a particular column, then that integer is in the top 2.5% of all the values.)

For this step, the M code will look like this (where `Source` is the previous step):

```
= Table.SelectRows( Source,
      (A) => List.Count( List.Select( Source[Integer], each _ > A[Integer] ) ) /
             List.Count( Source[Integer] )
      > 0.025 )
```

---

Another option would be to do it in DAX. For this, you'd just need to use the [`PERCENTILE.EXC` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/percentile-exc-function-dax) and filter out the top 2.5% either in a calculated table or in whatever measure you are using. (Since you specifically asked to remove it from the data set, I'm only detailing the Query Editor solution.)

Comment: what do you mean "in a calculated table or in whatever measure I am using"?  I sorted the data ascending based on the last column, which rearranged everything from small to big of course. Then to filter out the top 2.5%, I did `Measure = PERCENTILE.EXC(Dogs[Age], 0.025)` Does it seem correct to you how I did it? @alexis olsun

Comment: I just meant that whether you calculated the percentile as a measure or in a calculated column, you should be able to use that percentile value in a visual level filter or page level filter.